# VisualForce drop down button creation with a Link(action) associated to it

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, apexactionfunction

I need to create a drop down button(command) on my Visual Force page. This drop down should have a "Link"(or a lable-Text), when we click on this link it should invoke an action.

This design is achievable with the help of HTML, but i am unable to invoke my controller action inside the HTML.

Please find the below HTML code. I have kept the dropdown as Radio button

`<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Right Align">

  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:auto;font-size: 25px;"></span>
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><input type="radio" id="ID" name="NAME" value="VALUE"/><label for="ID">Label</label></li>
</ul>
    </div>`

My current output

[image]

Currently i have the action configured on apex:command button and please find the code for the same below

Please let me know how can i achieve my requirement and call the above mentioned apex action inside HTML.

If you have any other suggestion please let me know.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!checkOffersBasedOnEmailOrVIN}" status="mySaveStatus1" title="this tooltip" alt="this tooltip" image="{!URLFOR($Resource.Rforce_CommercialOffersCheckOffers_STR_Menu)}" style="height:30px;width: 40px;left: 10px;border: 2px solid #FF8C00" rerender="formId">
         <apex:param name="objType" assignTo="{!strObjectType}" value="Case"/> 
     </apex:commandButton>
```

Meanwhile i though of writing a Javascript to call an action function and that is not working!! Please find the code

```
<script>
function myJavascriptFunc()
{
    alert('Entered Javascript') ;
    CallApexMethod() ;
}
```

and  action function declared as

```
<apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!checkOffersBasedOnEmailOrVIN}" status="mySaveStatus1" onComplete="alert('After apex method') ;">
```

and the button design `<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Right Align">

  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:auto;font-size: 25px;"></span>
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><input type="button" name="myJavascriptFunc" value="Search Offers"/><label for="ID">Label</label></li>
</ul>
    </div>`

Comment: Your question is not very clear.
Do you want to call an action function on selection of radio button?

Comment: i want to call an action function onclick of a lable or text field (actually what ever u seen in screen shot should have been a link and not a radio button)